# Downloading csv file Loopback

Tags: loopback

I have this remote method in loopback

```
    Usermodel.exporting = function(type, resp, cb) {
    var result;
    var fields = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
    var data = ["First name ","last name"]
            result = json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields });
            resp.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=users.csv');
            resp.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
            resp.send(result);
        })
}
    Usermodel.remoteMethod('exporting', {
    accepts: [
        { arg: 'type', type: 'string' },
        { arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': { source: 'res' } }
    ],
    returns: {},
    http: { path: '/csvexport/:type', verb: 'get' }
});
```

I am trying to download csv file on client side this code is downloading the file but file is not in csv and it is also not formatted.What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting is a risky name for remote method :) ,lets say we rename it to myremote method the the correct syntax would be

```
module.exports = function(MyModel){

MyModel.myremote = function(msg, cb) {
  ..
}
MyModel.remoteMethod('myremote', {
      accepts: ..
});
};
```